# How to handle empty return from getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I have a php script which gets results from a DB, and to get those results I'm using a jQuery script to pull the results via getJSON. It works perfectly but now I want to do something if the php script returns no results (empty).

I tried:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/script'), {parameter:parameter}, function(data){
 if (data) {
  alert('Result');
 } else {
  alert('Empty);
 }
});
```

But it's no good. I've tried different things like if (data.length) but still nothing. I've noticed that if there is no returned data the callback will never fire at all. So if that's the case, how do I handle a empty return?

Comment: You may find http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ to be more useful, so you can handle more options, since an empty result isn't valid JSON, so there is nothing to parse, hence nothing for you to react to.

Comment: You're right, I also just realized that I can return a JSON encoded empty response which can then be checked by the callback. Err.. I really need to start thinking things through.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question, other people may run into the same question.

Comment: If the `success` callback isn't being fired, the `error` callback likely will be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check your PHP output to always output some data.

In my codes I add a success flag to my outputs, like this:

```
$result = array (
 'success' => true,
 'data' => $data
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

If I don't output anything, I put false into success, which makes it easy to validate in jQuery via data.success:

Example:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/script', {parameter:parameter}, function(data){
 if (data.success) {
  alert('Result');
 } else {
  alert('Empty');
 }
});
```

If you don't want to modify your output, you can setup an ajaxError to catch your reading problems.

Example:

```
$.ajaxError(function() {
 alert('error triggered');
});
```

P.S.: I dont know if the missing ' at the end of this line:

```
alert('Empty);
```

is really missing in your original, if so, your missing a ' ;-) >>

```
alert('Empty');
```

Comment: Second code block seems to miss a ( somewhere, the last one seems to match none. 
sorry, I'm not so well versed in the lang, so matching brackets of all types is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON('json.php?',function(r){

                try {
                    typeof(r[0].city);
                } catch (e) { return false; /* or do somthing */  } 
 [...]
```

Comment: This also guards against a broken service (which returns nothing at all, not even an empty JSON object).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), if you get nothing on the response, `.getJSON` will give you `null`. However, if you're passing something such as {}, you will end up with an `object` that has no such properties as `.length` and that will be regarded as `true` in an `if` condition.

If you need to identify an empty object, there may be a shorter way, but the one that occurs me at the moment is:

```
var isEmpty = true;
for (var p in data) { isEmpty = false; break; }
// at this point, if isEmpty should tell you if 'data' is an empty object
```

This poor code works assuming that `data` is of type object.

Comment: Should be `for (var p in data) {
if ( data.hasOwnProperty(p) ) { isEmpty = false; break; }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle empty responses in JS getting data from PHP!

response.php

```
if (check parameters from script.php) {
    $result  = $con->query(sqlAll($con)); // 'sqlAll()' returns a query like 'SELECT * FROM table'
    $arrData = array(); $i = 0; $tot = array(); $empty = ''; // '$empty' we'll use for empty response

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

           // fill array
           $arrData = array (
                'title'  => $row["post_title"],
                'author' => $row["post_author"]
            );

            $tot[$i] = $arrData; // collect data from '$arrData'
            $i++;
        }

        // tell PHP to become 'JSON-MASTER'
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo json_encode($tot); // transfer response to script.php
    }
    else echo json_encode($empty);
```

script.php

```
$('#search_txt').keyup(function(){ // instant search
    $.getJSON('response.php', {
        // some parameters to be sent
        },

        function(data){
            var row = "";
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {  
             row +=
                 '<h2>'+
                 '<a href="#">'+val.title+
                 '</a></h2>'+
                 '<p class="lead">'+
                 'by <a href="index.php">'+val.author+'</a>'+
                 '</p>';
            });

        $('.box').html(row); // display result to the page
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
return json_encode([]);
```

As a result, the jQuery success handler saw the response as an empty array:

```
$.getJSON("/url", function(data) {            
    console.log("data.length: " +  data.length); //  data.length: 0
}
```